# Spring boot maven multi module project with Spring Data

Tags: maven, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a spring boot(1.4.3.RELEASE) application with MySQL as a backend. Using Spring Data with Oracle UCP and MySQL Java connection for connection pooling. Now, trying to move it to a multi module project. Hence my project structure is as follows.

```
parent project
|---pom.xml  -> This is a parent pom.
|---common
    |---pom.xml
    |---src
|---model
    |---pom.xml
    |---src
|---service(Interface only)
    |---pom.xml
    |---src
|---service Impl(Implementations only)
    |---pom.xml
    |---src
|---repository(Spring Data)
    |---pom.xml
    |---src
|---web
    |---pom.xml
    |---src
```

My parent pom.xml is as follows:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                             http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-parent</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Test Project</name>
    <description>Test components</description>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>      
        <version.spring.boot>1.4.3.RELEASE</version.spring.boot>
        <version.mysql.connector>6.0.5</version.mysql.connector>
        <version.slf4j>1.7.21</version.slf4j>

    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- Spring -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
                <version>${version.spring.boot}</version>
                <optional>true</optional>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>${version.slf4j}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <modules>
    <module>cc-model</module>
    <module>cc-common</module>
    <module>cc-dbrepo</module>
    <module>cc-dbservice</module>
    <module>cc-dbserviceimpl</module>
    <module>cc-web</module>
</modules>

</project>
```

Application.java in web:

```java
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = 
            { "com.test.dbrepo.service.impl", "com.test.db.service", "com.test.dbrepo.repository" })
public class DialerApplication {
```

web pom.xml:

```xml
<dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>

       <dependency>
        <groupId>com.cc.dialer</groupId>
        <artifactId>cc-dbservice</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

In my repository pom.xml, I have spring-data

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

My DataSource code and the repositories are there in repository project.
I have my Spring security code in web module which uses Service module thru injection.

I am getting the below error when i start my web module application.

> Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field 'userDetailsService'; nested
>   exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsService': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field 'userService'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type 'com.cc.test.db.service.UserService'
>   available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Is there any other config missing.

Beans in the service impl module is not getting discovered when starting.

Thanks

Comment: The POM you show are incomplete, so we can't really help you here. You are missing a SQL datasource, where are your drivers declared? Embedded in tomcat in WAR run? Or jar included in spring-boot executable jar? Where is your mysql driver declared in maven?

Comment: have updated my post.

Comment: I'll delete my answer. I think there is a misunderstanding, caused by the words _"unsatisfied dependency"_ in the error message. Probably your maven POMs are correct, but there is an issue with your Spring bean definitions. You should post the essential parts of your code where you define your Spring beans **(Annotations ???)**.

Comment: Where is UserService? Is it included in maven? If yes, is it scanned properly by spring (auto-scan package)?

Comment: Hello. I am having exact same issue. What was the solution to your problem finally?

Answer (score -1):

Package com.cc.test.db.service is not scanned according to your configuration.

Add it.

Your annotation should look like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = 
            { "com.test.dbrepo.service.impl", "com.test.db.service", "com.test.dbrepo.repository", "com.cc.test.db.service" })
```

Comment: I tried that as well. Thou its not working. See the error what I get here is `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/imsx/core/repository/UserRepository (Module "deployment.imsx.ear.webx.war" from Service Module Loader): org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository`. Normally spring boot wont require componentscan if the main application is in the parent package.